# How to affect the vertical gap between the glossary's name and its body

Tags: spacing, glossaries, titlesec

I'm using the `glossaries` package for producing of nomenclature/symbols/acronyms lists, but I don't know how to influence the vertical gap between the glossary title and the first glossary entry. Namely, a smaller gap is needed. I've found a dirty hack how to make it smaller using `\begingroup` .. `\endgroup` and `\titlespacing*`, but is it possible to affect this gap with some glossaries-in-built means? Even when defining a new style, I don't know what property/command is responsible for this space.

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn,twoside,draft,titlepage,fleqn,a4paper,openright]{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym, toc, section, shortcuts, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}  % sets the line indent in glossaries
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{12.5cm}   
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syg}{Nomenclature}
\newglossary[ilg]{indices}{iyi}{iyg}{List of indices}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ECD}{ECD}{equivalent circuit diagram}
\newacronym{RES}{RES}{renewable energy source}
\newglossaryentry{Rx1}
{
  name={\ensuremath{R_{x1}}},
  description={Equivalent series resistance},
  sort=Rx1, type=symbols
}
\newglossaryentry{ref}
{
  name={*},
  description={Indicates reference value},
  sort=ref, type=indices
}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\glsaddall                                
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{4pt} % dirty hack
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long, title=List of Abbreviations and Acronyms]
\vspace{40pt} % Another dirty hack
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=long, title=Nomenclature]
\vspace{40pt} % Another dirty hack
\printglossary[type=indices, style=long, title=List of indices]
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command responsible for that space is the sectioning command used at the start of the glossary (`\section*` in your example). This makes it consistent with the structure throughout the rest of the document. By way of illustration:

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn,twoside,draft,titlepage,fleqn,a4paper,openright]{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym, toc, section, shortcuts, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}  % sets the line indent in glossaries
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{12.5cm}   
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syg}{Nomenclature}
\newglossary[ilg]{indices}{iyi}{iyg}{List of indices}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ECD}{ECD}{equivalent circuit diagram}
\newacronym{RES}{RES}{renewable energy source}
\newglossaryentry{Rx1}
{
  name={\ensuremath{R_{x1}}},
  description={Equivalent series resistance},
  sort=Rx1, type=symbols
}
\newglossaryentry{ref}
{
  name={*},
  description={Indicates reference value},
  sort=ref, type=indices
}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall                                
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long, title=List of Abbreviations and Acronyms]
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=long, title=Nomenclature]
\printglossary[type=indices, style=long, title=List of indices]

\section*{Sample}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
Some & Text
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

The gap between `\section*{Sample}` and the `longtable` is the same as the equivalent gap in the glossaries. If you really wanted to reduce this gap in the glossaries (although I don't recommend this) without changing the overall sectioning style you could redefine `\glossarypreamble` to add some negative space, for example:

```
\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
```

Incorporating this into the above example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,onecolumn,twoside,draft,titlepage,fleqn,a4paper,openright]{book} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, acronym, toc, section, shortcuts, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}  % sets the line indent in glossaries
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{12.5cm}   
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syg}{Nomenclature}
\newglossary[ilg]{indices}{iyi}{iyg}{List of indices}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ECD}{ECD}{equivalent circuit diagram}
\newacronym{RES}{RES}{renewable energy source}
\newglossaryentry{Rx1}
{
  name={\ensuremath{R_{x1}}},
  description={Equivalent series resistance},
  sort=Rx1, type=symbols
}
\newglossaryentry{ref}
{
  name={*},
  description={Indicates reference value},
  sort=ref, type=indices
}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\renewcommand*{\glossarypreamble}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}                                
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=long, title=List of Abbreviations and Acronyms]
\printglossary[type=symbols, style=long, title=Nomenclature]
\printglossary[type=indices, style=long, title=List of indices]

\section*{Sample}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
Some & Text
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: Image of resulting document]

Here the gap for the glossaries is smaller but the gap for the sample section remains the same as before.

Comment: Btw in my initial "solution", the section gap also remained unchanged for the rest of the document due to \begingroup .. \endgroup. But this is simply to be clear. Otherwise see above.

Comment: @Nicola Talbot, how can I change the space between rows, for example, for `superragged` style? knowing that I used the option `nogroupskip`.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou The `superragged` style uses the `supertabular` environment, so any of the standard tabular settings should work, for example, you could redefine `\arraystretch` to, say, `1.5` to increase the spacing.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Can you please tell how to reduce the spacing between the consecutive glossary entries? I tried a lot but I am not able to find an answer

Comment: @Rouge Make the value of `\arraystretch` smaller to reduce the inter-row spacing. Remember to use `nogroupskip` if you want to suppress the larger space between letter groups.